# Inductively prove $1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Inductively prove that the formula holds for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$:

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}=2-\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

What I have so far:

base: n = 1: $$1+\frac{1}{2}=2-\frac{1}{2}=1.5$$

inductionstep: n = k: $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}=2-\frac{1}{2^k}$$
inductionhypothesis: n=k+1: $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k+1}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^(k+1)}=(2-\frac{1}{2})+\frac{1}{2^k+1}$$

This is where I am stuck and not sure what to do next.

Comment: Induction? The geometric series formula is very simply proved by other means

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Multiply both sides on $2^n$ and, possibly, you'll find it more easy.

Comment: The induction step needs you to show $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ $=2-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.  You also need to start the induction, perhaps when $n=0$ or $1$

Comment: I have edited the orignal post with my own ideas and effort

Comment: Two errors after the last "=" in your induction hypothesis. Fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following structure:

**Step 1.** $n = 0$, means $1 = 2 - \frac{1}{2^0} = 2 - 1 = 1$, which is true. We can proceed to induction step.

**Step 2.** Use simple induction: $p(n) \to p(n + 1)$. So, if:
$$1 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^n}$$
We have:
$$1 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = 2 - \frac{2}{2^{n + 1}} + \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}}$$

This ends the proof. $\blacksquare$

Comment: why is changing $$\frac{1}{2^n}$$ to $$\frac{2}{2^(n+1)}$$ valid?

Comment: $2^{n+1} = 2 \cdot 2^n$; $\frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{2}{2 \cdot 2^n} = \frac{2}{2^{n + 1}}$

Answer (score 4):

The formula
$$
1+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}=2-\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
is true for $n=0$ (in which case the LHS of the equation actually only has one term in it). Therefore, it is better to choose $n=0$ as your base case. Now suppose it is true when $n=k$, that is
$$
1+\dots+\frac{1}{2^k}=2-\frac{1}{2^k} \, .
$$
Then, for $n=k+1$, we have
\begin{align}
1+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}&=\left(1+\dots+\frac{1}{2^k}\right)+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \\[5pt]
&= 2-\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \\[5pt]
&= 2-\frac{2}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \\[5pt]
&= 2-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \, .
\end{align}
Hence, if the statement is true for $n=k$, it is true for $n=k+1$. Since it is true for $n=0$, by the principle of mathematical induction it must be true for all nonnegative integers $n$.